# Where can I download the Antminer S9i Software

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

I would like to try putting some s9i software on my s9's but where can you download the s9i software or is that just the newest version of software that they have for the s9's. Where can I get the s9i software?

Comment: Firmwarescan be downloaded from https://shop.bitmain.com/support.htm but Bitmain is smart enough not to upload S9i's firmware. You'll need to dump a friend's S9i's firmware by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As MCCCS commented:

> Firmwares can be downloaded from [Bitmain](http://shop.bitmain.com/support.htm) but Bitmain is smart enough not to upload S9i's firmware. You'll need to dump a friend's S9i's firmware by yourself.

---

<sup>Comment converted to Community Wiki answer in attempt to remove this Q from list of unanswered questions</sup>

Comment: So are you sure there is no alternatives i have no friend with an s9i.

Comment: @Learn2Mine: Contact your hardware supplier Bitmain for the latest firmware.

Comment: https://shop.bitmain.com/support.htm?pid=00720180525135351672WCe9WPkv06BF Is this the firmware i need to flash onto that sd card